# Reinstalling Gatsby failing Errors

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have cloned a repo of a 1 year old Gatsby website to my local machine to make some changes, but when I try and reinstall/update it fails.

There are many deprecation warnings and some errors as below...

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path /Users/nickwild/Programming/NicciToppingCode/ntc2/node_modules/deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.7.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.2 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction to fix this

This is my package.json...

```
"dependencies": {
    "antd": "^4.19.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.0",
    "components": "^0.1.0",
    "gatsby": "^4.9.2",
    "gatsby-awesome-pagination": "^0.3.3",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^1.0.0",
    "gatsby-cli": "^4.10.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-antd": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-lodash": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^6.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-canonical-urls": "^1.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.9.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^6.9.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-json": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.9.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.9.0",
    "html-entities": "^2.0.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nuka-carousel": "^4.5.9",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.9.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-player": "^2.7.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.14",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^4.0.4",
    "rfs": "^9.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "n/a",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "clean": "rimraf .cache public",
    "build": "npm run clean && gatsby build",
    "develop": "npm run clean && gatsby develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "format": "prettier --trailing-comma es5 --no-semi --single-quote --write \"{gatsby-*.js,src/**/*.js}\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
```

Is there any easy way to unpick which packages are causing the problems?

Many thanks